# Toric variety associated to the cone over a polytope

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polytopes

Let $P = [0,m] \subset M_{\mathbb{R}^2}$ be the line segment and consider the cone over $P$.

> What is the toric variety of the cone over $P$?

The thing is I am not entirely sure how to construct a cone $\sigma$ from the polytope $P$. Should it just be the cone generated by $me_1$? In which case wouldn't we obtain the variety $\mathbb{C} \times T^1$, where $T$ denotes the torus?

What does the "affine variety of the cone of a polytope" actually mean? Sorry if this question looks too trivial, but I couldn't find any reference that answers this question explicitly.

Comment: Sorry, I made a wrong answer before, I think this one is correct now.

Answer (score 1):

First there is two ways to get a toric varieties : via fan or via polytopes. It seems you are considering the polytope version here, which looks strange because you took a 1-dimensional polytope in $\Bbb R^2$ which is a degenerate case. You can just look at $P \subset \Bbb R$ and you will get a projective line (but remember than a polytope is a bit more than simply a toric variety, it also gives you a divisor. In this case your segment correspond to $\mathcal O(m)$.

Here is a possible interpretation in general : suppose $P \subset M$ is your polytope. Embed $M$ in $M \times \Bbb R$ as $M \times {(0,1)}$ and take the cone over $P$ with respect to the origin. This gives you a polytope hence a toric variety.

P.S : for a segment, the associated toric variety is $\Bbb P^1, \Bbb C, \Bbb C^*$ depending if the segment is closed, half-closed or open.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The thing is that, shouldn't we get an affine variety if we are taking just a cone? How is in this case $\mathbb{P}^1$ a possible solution? I mean, I think I know how to get $\mathbb{P}^1$ and the three cases you mention correspond precisely to the three possible one-dimensional fans.

Comment: I thought that if, in this case, the polytope is just the convex hull of the points $0$ and $m$, then the cone would be generated by $(0,0), (0,1)$ and $(0,m)$, but this would result in a different affine toric variety, right?

Comment: @user313212 : as I said there are two different view points for toric varieties, polytope or fan (i.e union of cones). You need to work exclusively with one or the other. You started with a polytope, so this cone construction should give you another polytope. If the polytope itself is a cone does not imply that the variety will be affine (it's true if the fan is only constituted of a single cone). 
My "P.S" was just describing your initial variety, which is $\Bbb P^1$ I believe and not $\Bbb C \times \Bbb C^*$, but I could be mistaken of course. You can also look in Cox Little Schenck's book.

Comment: Don't you think the construction is a cone $\sigma$ generated by $(0,1), (m,0)$? In which case $S_{\sigma}$ is generated by $\{(0,1),(1,1), \dots , (m,1)\}$? Then $\mathbb{C}[S_{\sigma}] = \mathbb{C}[x_1, x_1x_2, x_1^2x_2, \dots , x_1^mx_2]$ and the corresponding affine toric variety is the locus of $xy - z^m$? Is this the affine toric variety defined by a polytope construction you are referring to?

Comment: @user313212 : the cone generated by $e_2, me_1$ is the same as the cone generated by $e_1, e_2$. You can see that $\Bbb C[x_1, \dots, x_1^mx_2] = \Bbb C[x_1,x_2]$. So I really think it's referring to a polytope. I think it's probably a polytope because a cone is never compact.